# AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask, fatal-error

I am new with App development and I am trying to make a login app with `JSONParser` but the problem is that it crashes whenever I try to `login`.

```
 06-30 15:06:32.415  16009-16052/com.zaid.sling.mysqltest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            ......
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

code is as follows

```
public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:1234/webservice/login.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //setup input fields
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        //setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

        //register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onPause(){

        super.onPause();
        if(pDialog != null)
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        super.onStop();

        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.login:
                new AttemptLogin().execute("username", "password");
                break;
            case R.id.register:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

   class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    boolean failure;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        int success;
        String username = args[0];
        String password = args[1];


        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                failure = false;
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

            }else{
                failure = true;
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
            }
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        if (failure == false) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComment.class);
           finish();
            Login.this.startActivity(i);
        }

    }
}
}
```

After updating my code with @Daniel one I got following stuff in my logcat.

```
07-01 14:28:35.969  12758-12876/com.zaid.sling.mysqltest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            ......
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.zaid.sling.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:143)
```

Comment: Where did you call this AttemptLogin AsyncTAsk? can you post that code

Comment: you haven't put argument while you execute to AsyncTask. `new AttemptLogin().execute(username, pw)`

Comment: How you calling this AttemptLogin Async, since you might not passing required parameter as an array. Use following:  "new AttemptLogin().execute(your_string_array);"

Comment: Change `new AttemptLogin().execute();` to `new AttemptLogin().execute("username",password);`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the error

```
 new AttemptLogin().execute();
```

This is wrong. You need to pass user name and password here.

```
 new AttemptLogin().execute("user_name", "password");
```

You are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error. Because there is no args pass to AsyncTask but you try to read like this

```
String username = args[0];
        String password = args[1];
```

So you need to pass the values to AsyncTask.

Comment: You must get an error. You need to add your user name and password new AttemptLogin().execute("user_name", "password");. I am showing an example "user_name" and "password". In that place you add your required user name and password

Comment: Ok Are you sure your latest logcat is correct? How did you post it?

Comment: this is line 143 of login.java    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

Comment: Your json is null.  Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString()+"**"); Try like this no error. But you need to find the reason why it is null

Comment: JsonParser.makeHttpRequest may return null object.

Comment: you may look into JsonParser.makeHttpRequest and find out what cause it return null

Comment: @Amsheer i uploaded JSONParser class , please help and thanks in advance

Comment: @cavinfly please check my JSONParser class

Comment: have you seen log from JSONParser like result or Error parsing data, may be add log if catch IOException too

Comment: @calvinfly can you explain in simpler way ?

Answer (score 0):

You might missing required parameter to pass as an array. 
Use following:

`new AttemptLogin().execute(your_string_array);`

For example refer [AsyncTask_Example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: call it this way: 
String[] credential = {"username", "password"};

new AttemptLogin().execute(credential);

Comment: I added latest log at the end of my post

Comment: Dear, you can start debugging you code. This may help you better. Or at least put log and check what you are getting null.